# How to handle bool arguments to a function?

Tags: python, boolean

Question is:
Compose a function odd() that takes three `bool` arguments and returns `True` if an odd number of arguments are `True`, and `False` otherwise.

For example, the output is:

```
>>> odd ( False , True , False )
True
>>>
>>> odd ( True , True , True )
True
>>>
>>> odd ( True , True , False )
False
```

This is question but I am not sure what I write as argument in function?
`def bool(x,y,z)` is it right? By the way, I tried one way to solve that question.

```
import sys

def bool(x,y,z):
    if x+y+z%2==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])
c = int(sys.argv[3])

m = bool(a,b,c)

print(m)
```

My way is very bad I know, but I am confused about boolean argument.
Are there anyone to show me a way?

Comment: You count how many _arguments_ are True or False and then do something with that information. You aren’t asked to do math with these arguments.

Comment: you should not overload `bool`

Comment: I can think true true false ---> false
true true true ----> true
but I don't know how to convert the boolean in this question.

Comment: Please include your question as **text** , not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function by removing `if` and `else` conditions and just 
write:

```
def boolean(x,y,z):
    return (x + y + z) % 2 == 1

print(boolean(False, False, False))   
print(boolean(False, False, True))
print(boolean(False, True, True))
print(boolean(True, True, True))
```

Output:

```
False
True
False
True
```

Also, you shouldn't use the name `bool` as a function name as it is a Python keyword. Try using a different one.

Comment: I didn't see your code. But i see now. You are absolutely right. thank you. I am late to write this. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is ok, you just forget parentheses.

```
def odd(x, y, z):
    return bool((x + y + z)%2)
```

You could easily extend this function to take an arbritrary number of arguments:

```
def odd(*bools):
    return bool(sum(bools)%2)
```

Comment: probably I don't understand how I can use boolean in this question.

Comment: @user9654395 my original answer was not so clever, I realized your approach is fine, you were just tripped up  by the fact that `%` has precedence over `+`.

Comment: Oooo it worked. I forget parentheses.
but others solutions different than me. You think it is acceptable for university? I mean, teacher will accept that this way?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry but my code is not right for of this question. but Thank you for interest.

Answer (score 3):

operator precendence evaluates `x+y+z%2` as `x+y+(z%2)`. what you want is `(x+y+z)%2`. (and `bool` is a built-in type; you should call your function something other than that...)

the function you are looking for is called [parity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function) .

if you accept `bool` as input type you might just `xor` (`^`) the three variables:

```
def odd(b0, b1, b2):
    return b0 ^ b1 ^ b2
```

tested with

```
from itertools import product

for b0, b1, b2 in product((True, False), repeat=3):
    print('odd({}, {}, {}) = {}'.format(b0, b1, b2, odd(b0, b1, b2)))
```

this could be generalized to accept an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce

def odd(*bools):
    return reduce(xor, bools, False)
```